# React-Native Cannot find Module '../../App'

Tags: react-native

When creating the SRC folder and inserting the appropriate items, react-native started giving this error:

```
AppEntry.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../App'

Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

index.js:1 ./node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../App'
  1 | import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
  2 |
> 3 | import App from '../../App';
  4 |
  5 | registerRootComponent(App);
```

From what I understand it is not finding the App with the path which is in "AppEntry.js".

However, AppEntry is by default in package.json:

```
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"
```

What should I do to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have moved your App.js or App.ts from root folder to 'src' so in appEntry you need to update your path from:

`import App from '../../App';`

To:
`import App from '../../src/App';`

Or you just can move back App.tsx to root folder

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the AppEntry was not created by me, it was the expo itself that generates it inside the node_modules, how can I change the path?

Comment: I know, just simply move <project_root>src/App.tsx to <project_root>

Comment: And for the record you can modify files under node_modules but we should try to find other ways first as it's not good approach

Comment: Wouldn't this movement be strange? By good practice would it be better to move all of the src out?

Comment: By default as far as I know expo projects have App.js/ts files under project root. I am not sure if it's changed. All I am saying is to move your file (App.ts) 1 step back, that's it should be at root. You can put all other files under src that you might want to create. I suggest you to check "default project structure of expo RN project".

Comment: Also check the picture that I recently have attached with my answer provided.

Comment: If nothing works out then in node_modules edit ./node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js at line 3 update with `import App from '../../src/App';` this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initializer path using the `"main"` property in package.json (note if you do so you need to write something like this.

```
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";


import App from "./App";
export default registerRootComponent(App);
```

An example is https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo/blob/83887627274afa1970b5a0861e7c7d2e27efecce/expo-app/src/init/index.ts#L10-L13

with the package.json line https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo/blob/rework/expo-app/package.json#L5

Doing this gives you more flexibility, and I generally don't see the downside to doing it.